# A strange problem with the last step of the OAuth2 authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, zapier, ringcentral

Well like the title suggest I am having a strange problem with the API OAuth2.0 I wanted to play with the API in the sandbox before deploying live like any sane person to start pulling call recordings. Well when I was setting up the Oauth and it was a pain but I got to work, or at least I thought until it asked me to add an address for the sandbox profile after accepting all the other steps in order to go any father. Every time I tried to add the address from the zapier login  window it kept telling me it failed to try again later. I thought no big deal I will just add it from the user profile and well what do you know that didn't work either. I than made a new extension with a new number and email to see if it was just the account that was messed up, or if the dev account couldn't use the API for whatever reason but again no dice same problems all the way down. I even tried using three different browser to see if anything would change but no dice (not like that really matters everything is chrome based these days). I am wondering if anyone else has had this problem, did I miss something really simple that I am clearly over looking since I am running on 4 hours of sleep for the last two days.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it, love a very tired programmer.

Comment: Have you set the redirect url? 
https://platform.zapier.com/docs/oauth#add-zapier-redirect-url-to-your-app

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into the same problems, make sure when making a POST request to ring central you put the paramotors in the body of the request.